# Python Yandex translate example

Tags: python, json, api, unirest, yandex

so for example I am trying to use `unirest` for this
so i put

```
base = 'translate.yandex.net'
post = '/api/v1.5/tr./getLangs?ui=en&key=' + api_key
request = unirest.get(base+post, headers={'accept' : "json"})
```

and the code says something about not a valid url this is directly from the docs.

What I am asking for is a working example on how to get this api to work with the `unirest` module. If not possible how would I use with another package.

This may be a stupid question but maybe I just don't comprehend the docs from Yandex.

**update** a link to the docs is here.
https://tech.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate-docpage/

Comment: *"this is directly from the docs"* - could you post a link to the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `http://` or `https://` in the base url:

```
base = 'http://translate.yandex.net'
post = '/api/v1.5/tr.json/getLangs?ui=en&key=' + api_key
request = unirest.get(base+post, headers={'accept' : "json"})
```

and it should be fine.

This is based on [yandex documentation](https://tech.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/getLangs-docpage/).

Comment: Well thanks. **facepalm** I finally got a response with that